# how to remove redudant heading on table

Tags: php

im trying to fetch data from mysqli and display it on the table. everything is find expect for the table heading where if there's 5 data, it will repeat the header 5 times for each data.

Any idea where im doing wrong? I'm suspecting on the if loop on my php code.
Below is the code.

PHP Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                        <?php
                            //get rows query
                            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM register");
                            if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
                                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                            ?>
                                      <table class="table">
                                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                                          <th>
                                           Name
                                          </th>
                                          <th>
                                            Age
                                          </th>
                                          <th>
                                            Gender
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Passport Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Nationality
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Citizen
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Address
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Caught Place
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Current Status
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Based At
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Family Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Company Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Name"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Age"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Gender"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["PassportNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Nationality"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Citizen"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Address"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CaughtPlace"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CurrentStatus"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["BasedAt"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["PhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["FamilyPhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CompanyPhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>

                                        <?php } }else{ ?>
                            <p>Data(s) not found</p>
                            <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
```

Table output:

Comment: just put the `<table>...` including the header _outside_ (before) the while loop. And the closing `</tbody></table>` after the loop obviously.

Answer (score -1):

When you said "I'm suspecting on the if loop on my php code", you were correct. Just move the table header, start of the body & end of the body out of the loop, leaving only the table rows within ...

```
// Moved this from inside the loop 
                                      <table class="table">
                                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                                          <th>
                                           Name
                                          </th>
                                          <th>
                                            Age
                                          </th>
                                          <th>
                                            Gender
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Passport Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Nationality
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Citizen
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Address
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Caught Place
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Current Status
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Based At
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Family Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                            <th>
                                            Company Phone Number
                                          </th>
                                        </thead>


<div class="table-responsive">
                                        <?php
                            //get rows query
                            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM register");
                            if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
                                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                            ?>
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Name"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Age"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Gender"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["PassportNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Nationality"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Citizen"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["Address"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CaughtPlace"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CurrentStatus"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["BasedAt"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["PhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["FamilyPhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                              <?php echo $row["CompanyPhoneNumber"]; ?>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                        <tbody>



                                        <?php } }else{ ?>
                            <p>Data(s) not found</p>
                            <?php } ?>


// Moved this from inside the loop 
                                   </tbody>
                                  </table>

                                    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mawg! Really appreciate your help!! It's working now!

Comment: No problems, we are here to help. You had, in any case, guessed yourself that it was a looping error. Don't forget to accept the answer, and upvote it ;-)

Comment: Lolx!! Three years later, I notice that the OP has stated that it works - but has not accepted the answer - and someone  has downvoted without saying why. Just another day on S.O :-)